# Why is my Docker container exposed as TCP instead of HTTP on Docker Cloud

Tags: docker, tcp, docker-cloud

I'm creating a Docker service using Docker Cloud. I created the service using the Docker Cloud website but, my container is exposed as a TCP endpoint and not a HTTP endpoint

`Container endpoint: tcp://hadoop-cff9a38e-1.67ae8643.cont.dockerapp.io:32773`

According to the Docker cloud tutorial, it is possible to have a HTTP endpoint: this is seen in the example for the `dockercloud/hello-world` Docker Cloud service (See [Link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/your_first_service/) here...)

Anyone know why Docker cloud services are exposed as TCP instead of HTTP or how I can access my service using a browser?

Comment: Did you try hitting it on http?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work

Comment: Showing your service definition/configuration could help

Answer (score 0):

It's because the port is in the range of 3000.
If you expose your container on 80 or 8000 you will have HTTP instead of TCP.

Comment: Could you point me to the Docker Cloud documentation page that explains this functionality?